# Stop r from installing binary packages

Tags: r, rstudio, install.packages

Since I've been working with R there has always been the question " Do you want to install from sources the package which needs compilation?" 
I'm a beginner and I roughly understand what the message means. I currently don't want to install binary packages. Now from today on suddenly this messages no longer pops up, instead, r seems to automatically install binary packages ("downloaded binary packages are in...")
As I'm now having trouble correctly installing them, does someone know how to stop r from automatically downloading binary packages?

Comment: There are several mentions in [`?install.packages`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/install.packages.html) that reference options such as `type` and `"install.packages.compile.from.source"`. Have you checked and/or changed these? (`options` can be set on a global level.)

Comment: No, I haven't changed anything... Do you maybe have a tip on how to define type in install.packages? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `install.packages(..., type="source")`?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utils/versions/3.6.2/topics/install.packages), you can set the `type` argument as `source`, `binary`, etc.

*For example, if I'm trying to install the package `IRkernel`, this is what I'd do.*

**Install source**:
`install.packages("IRkernel", type="source")`

**Install binary**:
`install.packages("IRkernel", type="binary")`

***NOTE***:
Per the section "Binary packages" section of the documentation, there are other types available depending on your OS (i.e, `mac.binary`, `mac.binary.el-capitan`, `win.binary`, etc.)